# If statement proposed by Xcode doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, swiftui

I wanted to change the Status Bar color by using `.toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)` but it's only available for iOS 16.

So I clicked on `Add 'if #available' version check` to see what Xcode could propose and the result seemed perfect:

```
.if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

But unfortunately Xcode seems to not recognize its own solution because I get this error: `#available may only be used as condition of an 'if', 'guard' or 'while' statement`.

How would you resolve this problem (knowing that my app is available for iOS 15 and higher):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                Text("Hello")
            }
            // .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Does it really recommend the dot at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, at first I thought it was something new but it doesn't work!

Comment: The recommendation should wrap ScrollView inside `if #available`

Comment: the dot preceding if (`.if`) looks like a typo. Try removing it.

Comment: Without the dot it's a fatal error.